# How do I detect the Enter key in an edit box?

Tags: delphi, keyboard-events

I have a UDP messenger with a Send button, but it annoys me that I have to press the button instead of just hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. So I have created procedure `TForm1.Edit2KeyPress`. Now I have no idea how to define the Enter button in `if (enter is pressed) then {code for sending message}`.

After answering i have new problem. Anything I type is sended , letter by letter.. here is my code
    unit chat1;

```
interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, IdSocketHandle, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
   Button1: TButton;
   Memo1: TMemo;
Edit1: TEdit;
Button2: TButton;
Edit2: TEdit;
Label1: TLabel;
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
procedure Edit2KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
private
Activated: Boolean;
procedure SearchEvent(ResultIP, ResultName: String);
procedure UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
  ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
procedure UDPException(Sender: TObject);
public
end;

var
Form1: TForm1;
ss:string  ;

implementation

uses UDP;

{$R *.dfm}



procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  UDPSearchForm.SearchEvent := SearchEvent;
  UDPSearchForm.Left := Left;
  UDPSearchForm.Top := Top;
  UDPSearchForm.AktIP := Edit1.Text;
UDPSearchForm.SearchPartner;
end;

procedure TForm1.SearchEvent(ResultIP, ResultName: String);
begin
  Edit1.Text := ResultIP;
  Label1.Caption := ResultName;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
var
  s, s2: String;
begin
  if Activated then exit;
  Memo1.Clear;
  Activated := true;
  UDPSearchForm.OnUDPRead := UDPRead;
  UDPSearchForm.OnException := UDPException;
  UDPSearchForm.Active := true;
  s := UDPSearchForm.LocalAddress;
  s2 := UDPSearchForm.WSGetHostByAddr(s);
  Memo1.Lines.Add('I''m (' + s + ') ' + s2);
end;

procedure TForm1.UDPRead(Sender: TObject; AData: TStream;
   ABinding: TIdSocketHandle);
var
  Buffer: Array [0..2047] of Byte;
  count: Integer;
  PeerIP: String;
  PeerPort: Integer;
  s: String;
  i: Integer;
begin
  PeerIP := ABinding.PeerIP;
  PeerPort:= ABinding.PeerPort;
  count := AData.Size;
  if count > Length(Buffer) then begin
    exit;
  end;
  AData.Read(Buffer, count);
  if (Buffer[0] <> $00) and  (Buffer[0] <> $01) then begin  // not search
    Edit1.Text:= PeerIP;
  end;
  case Buffer[0] of
   $00: begin   // search request
    case count of
     4: begin
      case Buffer[1] of
       0: begin
        Buffer[0] := $01;
         UDPSearchForm.Host := PeerIP;
         UDPSearchForm.DoSend(Buffer, 4, Length(Buffer));
        Memo1.Lines.Add('Inquiry [' + UDPSearchForm.WSGetHostByAddr(PeerIP) + '(' +     PeerIP + ')' +          ' Port: ' + IntToStr(PeerPort) +
      ']');
   end;
  end;
 end;
end;
   end;
   $01: begin // Search Reply
    case count of
     4: begin
      case Buffer[1] of 0:
        begin
        ss := UDPSearchForm.WSGetHostByAddr(PeerIP);
    s := '[' + ss + '(' + PeerIP + ')' +
      ' Client Port: ' + IntToStr(PeerPort) +
      ']';
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Inquiry Reply ' + s);
    if PeerIp = UDPSearchForm.LocalAddress then begin
      ss := '<myself>' + ss;
    end;
    UDPSearchForm.Add(PeerIP, ss);
    end;
   end;
  end;
 end;
end;
    $10: begin // Text
     case Buffer[1] of
      0: begin
       s := '';
           for i := 4 to count-1 do begin
             s := s + char(Buffer[i]);
           end;
       Memo1.Lines.Add(ss+'  says: ' + s);
      end;
     end;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.UDPException(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //nothing
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  x: Array[0..100] of Byte;
  i: Integer;
begin
  UDPSearchForm.Host := Edit1.Text;
  UDPSearchForm.Active := true;
  x[0] := $10; // Text
  x[1] := 0;   // Type 0
  for i := 1 to Length(Edit2.Text) do begin
    x[i+3] := Byte(Edit2.Text[i]);
  end;
  UDPSearchForm.DoSend(x, 4+Length(Edit2.Text), length(x));

   Memo1.Text:=Memo1.Text+Edit2.Text+#13#10;
end;

procedure TForm1.Edit2KeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char);
var
  x: Array[0..100] of Byte;
  i: Integer;
begin
if Ord(Key) = VK_RETURN then
  UDPSearchForm.Host := Edit1.Text;
  UDPSearchForm.Active := true;
  x[0] := $10; // Text
  x[1] := 0;   // Type 0
  for i := 1 to Length(Edit2.Text) do begin
    x[i+3] := Byte(Edit2.Text[i]);
  end;
  UDPSearchForm.DoSend(x, 4+Length(Edit2.Text), length(x));

   Memo1.Text:=Memo1.Text+Edit2.Text+#13#10;


end;

end.
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the [`Default`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.StdCtrls.TButton.Default) property of the Send button to True. Its `OnClick` event will fire automatically when the user presses Enter.

Comment: Thanyou, that was the solution for my problem  =)

Comment: One benefit of this approach over manual keyboard event handling is the visual cue provided on the rendering of the default button.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan he might probably also use TEdit with embedded button, liek one from RxLib/JediVCL or like http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ExtCtrls.TButtonedEdit

Comment: @David but this did not solve the question... what if you only want the enter to trigger the onclick, if the user is in the editbox? or memo in my case

Comment: @GlenMorse How does your problem relate to this question? Specifically, why is it relevant that this accepted answer to this question does not solve your different problem?

Comment: @David well what i was wondering is how to detect if the enter key is hit while in an Editbox (only).. i did add the only as i took it that way after all it does say WHILE in editbox....as the title ask..

Comment: @GlenMorse Listen to the `OnKeyPress` event of the edit box. Also, why are you addressing this to me? Do you see that this is not even my answer!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ahh sorry, i just saw your name in the comments. Thanks :d